# Excel Dropdown boxes

Tags: excel

Working on a project and should be simple to solve but I'm having a hard time.
the data im working with is messy aswell, so duplicates values can be find in the Country and city cols.
The concept is simple:-

1. You select a Country from a dropdown list
2. select a city from a 2nd dropdown box that relates to the Country
3. select a site from a 3rd dropdown box that relates to the city.

Can have many cities to a Country and many sites to the city.

Extract from a sample data :-

[image]

Any ideas would be great.

Followed some vids and got to use this :-
=IFERROR(INDEX(AllData1[Country1],MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($K$2:K2,AllData1[Country1]),),0)),"")
Which gets me the unique values for Countries

Thanks

Comment: You need conditional dropdown lists. Take a look at https://trumpexcel.com/dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NAMES` and `INDIRECT` in Excel to get your desired conditional dropdown lists.
Name all the corresponding lists and then use `INDIRECT` function to call them along with a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` function when specifying the list in `data validation` menu.

I hope the the formula and pattern is clear in the following image:
[image]

```
=INDIRECT(INDEX($F$3:$F$11,MATCH($C$2,$E$3:$E$11,0)))
```

Comment: I see what you done here, i did think this might work, but the actual data size is like 1000, im trying to aviod making 100s of tables and names, if possible

Comment: Hmmm... Yes the above solution would be time consuming for that. Take a look at this video by Leila Gharani: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waqzwMCYD9I She points out couple of good ideas like dynamic names and transpose that maybe could help in your case.

Comment: So i come up with the following  :- =OFFSET(C1,MATCH(H4,B2:B900,0),0,COUNTIF(B2:B901,H4),1)  it does return cites from that Country, but it also returns all cites even if it entered more than once